# TransferSpreadsheet Misses ~200 Records - Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am writing a script to export two queries to excel spreadsheets. From there, I run a macro in another workbook that handles the data. Everything works fine, except that the data that is originally exported has missing records (around 200 each time).

My Code:

```
'Step 1: Run qry_OpenKaizens and ouput data to OpenKaizens.xlsx
    myQueryName = "qry_OpenKaizens"
    myExportFileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\OpenKaizens.xlsx"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, myQueryName, myExportFileName, True
'Step 2: Rim qry_closed Kaizens and output data to ClosedKaizens.xlsx
    myQueryName = "qry_ClosedKaizens"
    myExportFileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\ClosedKaizens.xlsx"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, myQueryName, myExportFileName, True
```

qry_OpenKaizens (should have 79 records, has 71):

```
SELECT KaizenData.TrackingNumber, KaizenData.KaizenLevel, KaizenData.Plant, KaizenData.Year1, KaizenData.[Tracking No], KaizenData.MainPillar, KaizenData.Area AS Dept, KaizenData.Team AS Area, KaizenData.[OP/STA] AS [Machine/Station], KaizenData.ProjectName AS [Project Name], KaizenData.IssueDescription AS [Description Phenomena], KaizenData.SolutionDescription AS [Solution Description], KaizenData.[Project Board], KaizenData.[Loss Category], KaizenData.[Loss Type], KaizenData.EnteredDate AS [Entered Date], KaizenData.StartingDate AS [Starting Date], KaizenData.EndDate AS [Completion Data], KaizenData.Notes, KaizenData.EstimatedSavings, KaizenData.EstimatedCost, KaizenData.BC, [EstimatedSavings]-[EstimatedCost] AS [Estimated Benefit], IIf([openstatus]=True,"Open") AS Status
FROM KaizenData
WHERE (((IIf([openstatus]=True,"Open")) Is Not Null));
```

qry_ClosedKaizens (should have 7514 records, but has 7239):

```
SELECT KaizenData.TrackingNumber, KaizenData.KaizenLevel, KaizenData.Plant, KaizenData.Year1, KaizenData.[Tracking No], KaizenData.MainPillar, KaizenData.Area AS Dept, KaizenData.Team AS Area, KaizenData.[OP/STA] AS [Machine/Station], KaizenData.ProjectName AS [Project Name], KaizenData.IssueDescription AS [Description Phenomena], KaizenData.SolutionDescription AS [Solution Description], KaizenData.[Project Board], KaizenData.[Loss Category], KaizenData.[Loss Type], KaizenData.EnteredDate AS [Entered Date], KaizenData.StartingDate AS [Starting Date], KaizenData.EndDate AS [Completion Data], KaizenData.[Wk Comp], KaizenData.Benefit, KaizenData.Cost, KaizenData.BC, KaizenData.Savings, IIf([closedstatus]=True,"Closed") AS Status
FROM KaizenData
WHERE (((IIf([closedstatus]=True,"Closed")) Is Not Null));
```

Comment: The only time I've had issues like that, the problem was something in the coding. Are you sure that the Excel macro isn't changing the data that was exported from Access? What's going on before and after the segment of code that you posted? If you run a make-table in access from the queries, do you get the same recordcount that the original queries have in select view? If not, at least you can narrow the issue to Access.

Comment: @PractLogical I thought the same thing at first, and checked me pre and post-import macros. Nothing touches that worksheet at all! I changed the workbook to self-import the data rather than using access to export the data and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something is going wrong with your where statement, not the export transaction.

Should the iif statement not be on your select line and your where statement just evaluate Closed or Open ?

What happens when closedstatus is null or empty or contains a blank ?